# How to fetch entries in custom plugin Craft 3?

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, search

I am creating custom search based on entries. I need to fetch entries in custom plugin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For instance like this:

```
$entries = Entry::find()
    ->section('sectionName')
    ->orderBy('fieldName')
    ->limit(null)
    ->all();
```

Have a look here in the documentation (for the code examples you can toggle Twig and PHP view for code examples):
https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html

Note that if you add `use craft\elements\Entry;` to the top of your plugin file, you can use the `Entry::find()` directly, you don't need the namespace prefix like in the examples in the documentation (for instance `\craft\elements\Entry::find();`).